# como filtrar o que aparecerá no Recyclerview

Tags: android, android-studio, android-adapter, android-recyclerview, calendar

Quero filtrar o que vai aparecer no RecyclerView, é possível?

Existe um CalendarView e eu quero que quando alguém clica em um dia a partir do calendarview, ele mostre itemviews apenas daquela data, por exemplo, quando alguém clicar no dia 15 do mês pode, ele mostre apenas as tarefas daquele dia

Não sei se é possível. Se alguém puder me ajudar, seria ótimo.

```
package com.iza.letfly;

import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.graphics.Paint;
import android.os.Build;
import android.preference.PreferenceManager;
import android.text.Html;
import android.util.SparseBooleanArray;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.CheckBox;
import android.widget.CompoundButton;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView;

import com.google.android.gms.tasks.OnFailureListener;
import com.google.android.gms.tasks.OnSuccessListener;
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth;
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseUser;
import com.google.firebase.firestore.DocumentReference;
import com.google.firebase.firestore.FirebaseFirestore;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

public class AdapterDoes extends RecyclerView.Adapter<AdapterDoes.MyViewHolder> {

    Context context;
    ArrayList<Mydoes> mydoes;
    FirebaseFirestore firestore;
    FirebaseUser user;


    public  AdapterDoes(Context c, ArrayList<Mydoes> p){
       context = c;
       mydoes = p;

    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public MyViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup ViewGroup, int i) {
        return new MyViewHolder(LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.item_does, ViewGroup, false));
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull MyViewHolder myViewHolder, int i) {
        myViewHolder.titleDoes.setText(mydoes.get(i).getTitleDoes());
        myViewHolder.DescribeDoes.setText(mydoes.get(i).getDescribeDoes());
        myViewHolder.dateDoes.setText(mydoes.get(i).getDateDoes());
        myViewHolder.alarm.setText(mydoes.get(i).getAlarm());
        myViewHolder.checkBox2.setText(mydoes.get(i).getCheck());

        myViewHolder.checkBox2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {


                    if (myViewHolder.checkBox2.isChecked()){
                        myViewHolder.checkBox2.setChecked(false);
                    }else{
                        myViewHolder.checkBox2.setChecked(true);
                    }

                }
        });

        if(myViewHolder.checkBox2.getText().equals("CHECKED")){
            myViewHolder.checkBox2.setChecked(true);
                myViewHolder.titleDoes.setAlpha(0.4f);
                myViewHolder.DescribeDoes.setAlpha(0.5f);
            myViewHolder.DescribeDoes.setPaintFlags(myViewHolder.DescribeDoes.getPaintFlags() | Paint.STRIKE_THRU_TEXT_FLAG);
            myViewHolder.titleDoes.setPaintFlags(myViewHolder.titleDoes.getPaintFlags() | Paint.STRIKE_THRU_TEXT_FLAG);
        }


        if(myViewHolder.checkBox2.getText().equals("UNCHECKED")){
            myViewHolder.checkBox2.setChecked(false);
        }


        myViewHolder.itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {


            final String getTitleDoes = mydoes.get(i).getTitleDoes();
            final String getDescribeDoes = mydoes.get(i).getDescribeDoes();
            final String getDateDoes = mydoes.get(i).getDateDoes();
            final String getAlarm = mydoes.get(i).getAlarm();
            final String getKeyDoes = mydoes.get(i).getKeyDoes();
            final String getCheck = mydoes.get(i).getCheck();


            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent i = new Intent(context,Edit_Check.class);
                i.putExtra("titleDoes",getTitleDoes);
                i.putExtra("DescribeDoes",getDescribeDoes);
                i.putExtra("dateDoes",getDateDoes);
                i.putExtra("alarm",getAlarm);
                i.putExtra("keyDoes",getKeyDoes);
                i.putExtra("check", getCheck);
                context.startActivity(i);
            }
        });



    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {

        return mydoes.size();
    }

    class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

        TextView titleDoes,DescribeDoes,dateDoes, alarm, keyDoes;
        CheckBox checkBox2;


        public MyViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            titleDoes = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.titleDoes);
            DescribeDoes = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.DescribeDoes);
            dateDoes = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.dateDoes);
            alarm = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.alarm);
            checkBox2 = (CheckBox) itemView.findViewById(R.id.checkBox2);



        }


    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

O RecyclerView vai mostrar os dados que ele tiver, no caso do seu código, ele vai mostrar os dados em `mydoes`. Se você quer filtrar o resultado no RecyclerView, a melhor forma é filtrá-los externamente (ex. no seu ViewModel/Fragment/Activity quando a pessoa selecionar uma data) e passar os novos dados filtrados pro RecyclerView. Você pode fazer isso adicionando um novo método que recebe os novos dados:

```
public void setData(ArrayList<Mydoes> newMydoes) {
    mydoes = newMydoes;
    notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

Não se esqueça dessa chamada ao `notifyDataSetChanged()` pra avisar pro RecyclerView que os dados foram atualizados, senão mesmo alterando o `mydoes`, o RecyclerView não atualiza visualmente. Na prática, ao chamar esse método, ele vai chamar novamente o seu `getItemCount()` pra ver a nova quantidade de dados, e chamar um `onBindViewHolder()` (e possivelmente `onCreateViewHolder()`) pra cada elemento do novo `mydoes` pra atualizar as views corretamente. Na verdade, eu sugiro usar a classe `androidx.recyclerview.widget.DiffUtil` ao invés de chamar o método `notifyDataSetChanged()` pra notificar que seus dados mudaram, pois o `DiffUtil` roda mais rápido e ainda faz animações entre os elementos durante essa alteração.